# scripted ssh command occasionally hangs indefinitely, server is alive and accepting connections

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I am automating some tests which run in the cloud ([GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute) to be specific).

I provision the VM, and then run through a number of setup steps using ssh.

Occasionally ssh will just hang indefinitely, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Initially I used [`paramiko.exec_command`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command), but I found [this issue](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/515) from 2015 which remains unresolved, so I decided to instead try vanilla ssh commands via [`subprocess.run`](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/515)

After the VM is created it takes a while to boot up and for sshd to start listening. As such I first run the command `true` over ssh in a loop until it succeeds:

```
retries = 6
while True:
    # just run 'true' on the remove server so if it executes successfully we know 
    # sshd is alive and accepting connections
    cmd = ('ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no '
           '-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null {user}@{host} true').format(
           user=user, host=host)
    r = subprocess.run(cmd,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                       shell=True)
    if r.returncode == 0:
        break
    retries -= 1
    if retries == 0:
        raise UnableToConnect()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Once `true` is run successfully I know the server is alive and accepting ssh connections, so I can continue with my setup steps.

```
def run_cmd(user, host, cmd):
    cmd = ('ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no '
           '-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null {user}@{host} {cmd}').format(
           user=user, host=host, cmd=shlex.quote(cmd))
    r = subprocess.run(cmd,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                       shell=True)
    return {
        'returncode': p.returncode,
        'stdout'    : p.stdout.decode("utf-8").rstrip(),
        'stderr'    : p.stderr.decode("utf-8").rstrip(),
    }
```

Most of the time everything works as expected, but on occasion, an ssh command will never return, hanging indefinitely.

One such example is that I need to install `binutils`:

```
run_cmd(user, vm_ip_addr, 'dpkg -s binutils || sudo apt-get install -y binutils')
```

The command never returns.

```
$ ps -ef | grep ssh
steve 31855 ... 00:00:00 /bin/sh -c ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null fred@123.123.123.123 'dpkg -s binutils || sudo apt-get install -y binutils'
steve 31856 ... 00:00:00 ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null fred@123.123.123.123 dpkg -s binutils || sudo apt-get install -y binutils
```

I attached to the `ssh` command using `strace` and it is stuck in a read:

```
$ sudo strace -p 31856
strace: Process 31856 attached
read(5,
```

(I'm not very skilled with `strace` so I'm not sure if there was anything else I could do to get more information at this point)

I know the server is alive, as I am able to ssh onto it, and prior to running the command which got stuck my script successfully ran `true` on the remove server.

**Questions:**

- Why is this command getting stuck?
- How can I detect this and/or prevent this?

Comment: I'm occasionally experiencing similar problem and strongly suspect it's because of terrible network quality misconfigured to the point connection can die, but your connection does not even get properly dropped (packets silently disappear and it appears to hang in a limbo). Long story short, perhaps try setting/using: `ServerAliveInterval`, check `man ssh_config` for details, you can also pass it on cmdline via `-o`; to at least detect the situation and terminate the process. For ongoing connection there is no timeout, so you'd have to implement watchdog from the outside.

Comment: When you use ssh to invoke a command on a remote system, it's normal for the local ssh instance to continue running until the remote command is finished. You should investigate what is happening on the remote server when this happens.